# Python script not running as cronjob

Tags: python, cron, crontab

I have tried everything and I've seen other questions here regarding this but I cannot for the life of me run a python script as a cronjob.

I've tried the following.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/myhome/myscript.py
```

All `myscript.py` does is a sleep for 30 seconds so I can check processes if it is running but I have yet to see it.

```
import time
time.sleep(30)
```

What am I missing? Shouldn't this run?  I've even tried opening a file in /tmp and outputting there but no luck.  I'm assuming its some environment variable issue but im not sure where to start.

BTW this runs fine on command line.

Comment: What happens if you direct `stdout` and `stderr` to a file (`python myscript.py > /tmp/myscript.log 2>&1`?  Do you see any errors?  Are you sure that Python is `/usr/bin/python`? What do you see in your local cron log?

Comment: @larsks No file was created in tmp. I don't see any errors.  syslog shows it trying to run though.     
    Jan 15 17:13:02 VirtualBox CRON[31926]:  CMD (/usr/bin/python /home/myusername/test.py > /tmp/myscript.log 2>&1)

Comment: Are you able to `strace` it? One of the most valuable commands for diagnosing problems, I find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this should run fine, assuming when you say "it runs fine on the command line" you're literally pasting the same command from the crontab entry. Things to check:

1. Is the cron daemon actually running? (Run `pidof cron`)
2. If it is running, try restarting it. (Depends on your flavour of Unix, but something like `service cron restart` or `/etc/init.d/cron restart`)
3. If your script still doesn't run, check everything in `/var/log` for appropriate output - the specific file depends on your syslog configuration, but `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog` are good options if `/var/log/cron` doesn't exist.

Note: You'll need to be `root` to do most of these things - if you don't have access then you'll need to speak to the person who administers the machine.

Also, when you say you open a file in `/tmp`, that's probably the most reliable thing you can do to ensure it's running. Right at the start of your script (before imports or anything) add this:

```
with open("/tmp/testfile", "a") as fd:
    fd.write("I am running\n")
```

You can also check if your crontab is being correctly installed - it should be placed in something like `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` (that's on Ubuntu Linux, it may differ on different Unix flavours). You should see a file in there with your username which should contain your entry.

Finally, if you get really desperate you could `strace` your cron process to see what it's doing:

```
sudo strace -f -p `pidof cron`
```

You don't need to worry too much about the specifics, but it should be doing *something* every minute. If it's not then something's going quite wrong.

Comment: +1. But actually, you don't need to be root to do most of these things. Traditional *nix, and most modern systems, make the syslogs world-readable, allow per-user crontabs, etc. And, although it isn't required, most modern cron implementations will let you run a separate per-user instance of the cron daemon for testing.

Comment: Perhaps "most" was a bit of a stretch, but I just wanted to make clear that an unprivileged user couldn't expect to be able to do all those things, to try and preempt confusion over resultant errors. I've seen a number of systems where most or all of `/var/log` was only available to root - I assumed people set conservative permissions in case any credentials ever leaked out into log files. This does certainly differ system to system, though - I've always found the lack of consistency in logging between unices a bit lamentable.

Comment: I'm getting this in the strace:   [pid  1760] execve("/usr/local/bin/bash", ["/usr/local/bin/bash", "-c", "python /home/username/test.py"], [/* 5 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: I have another cron job that is running fine with the same error.

Comment: Weird thing is I've tried this on Ubuntu and on a MAC.  No luck on both.

Comment: Looks like something has overridden the shell which cron is using to invoke jobs to `/usr/local/bin/bash` which, unsurprisingly, doesn't exist. The shell is specified by the `SHELL` environment variable and usually defaults to `/bin/sh` - check you're not setting a new value of this variable in your crontab, and then check `/etc/crontab` (can't remember if user crontabs "inherit" from this but worth a check). Also make sure your shell in `/etc/passwd` is set to something sensible (I assume it is or you'd have trouble logging in, but again worth checking).

Comment: As an aside, for future reference you should also check for the existence of `cron.allow` and `cron.deny` in either `/etc` or `/var/spool/cron` (depends on your system) as these can prevent some users using cron at all if they exist. However, your error seems to point to the wrong shell being used.

Comment: I actually had almost exactly this problem a few years ago. I installed MacPorts `bash` on a Mac, so `/opt/local/bin/bash` ended up in `/etc/shells`. Later, I upgraded (from 10.5 to 10.6? I forget), and all of my cronjobs were migrated, and all of the system jobs ended up running as a new user whose shell was `/opt/local/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`, meaning it ran `/etc/bash_profile`, which caused some problem or other…