# cronjob not executing python script - tried strace

Tags: linux, python, cron

I'm having trouble making a python script run via cronjob.

I can run the python script (it's supposed to connect to a database, pull a few records, save that to a csv, then email it) manually just fine. However, I can't get it to run. It's supposed to run every minute, for testing.

Here's the line in the crontab -e:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /appl/belo_monthly/belo_monthly.py > /appl/belo_monthly/results.log
```

I've used `chmod -x` on the file. I've also tried to write out the `print` lines of the file to a log. None are working - won't even create .log file.

The python file has `#!/usr/bin/python` at the very top.

**What I tried:**

I looked it up here, and found this: [Python script not running as cronjob](https://superuser.com/questions/537010/python-script-not-running-as-cronjob)

Using that as a reference:

1. Yup, cron daemon is running. `pidof cron` returns a value.
2. A lot of other services depend on this, so I can't restart it.
3. `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` gets me the following:

> Mar 31 10:21:01 ip-XX-XXX-XXX-XX CRON[30223]: (ubuntu) CMD
>   (/usr/bin/python /appl/belo_monthly/belo_monthly.py >
>   /appl/belo_monthly/results.log)

And it adds another line like that a minute later.

4. Finally, I tried this: `sudo strace -f -p pidof cron`. Which returned this:

> execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/python
>   /appl/belo_month"...], [/* 6 vars */]) = 0

And then some garbled mess of text later, this:

```
open("/appl/belo_monthly/results.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "/bin/sh: 1: ", 12) = 12
write(2, "cannot create /appl/belo_monthly"..., 63) = 63
write(2, "\n", 1)           = 1
exit_group(2)
```

So I'm thinking, it can't create a log. But what about the python script? What happened?

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727935/execute-python-script-on-crontab Hope this could solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure as to what to try from that question and answer. The cron is working, and I can google how to setup the frequency correctly. For reference, I'm already using `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top of my python files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> won't even create .log file

Does the user you set the cronjob for have write access to /appl/belo_monthly/results.log? Did you create the cronjob as regular user or as root?

Comment: I didn't create the cronjob, unfortunately. I don't need to use `sudo` when editing it, and using root via `sudo su` and doing `crontab -e` creates a new, empty cron if it means anything.

Comment: I added a `sudo` to the command in the cron job. Finally worked. Though I understand there are / could be some security issues regarding this.